# How to use two controls for movie player?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have created a movie player. I'm using the default windows control for **Media Player**. However I just saw that some movies do not work under it(some FLV files). However those files do work under **Media Player Classic**. So I was thinking about using the Media Player Classic control.

However

I want this movie player to be **as portable as possible**. So what I would like to do is to use Media Player Classic control when its **available in system**, but if **its NOT** than use Media Player control.

Is that even possible or do I need to create two applications that share the same code?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using libvlc. VLC is really good about playing almost anything you give it. It is a C API but one could possibly DllImport their way to success and write code in C#.

Here are some good resources to get you started:

- http://wiki.videolan.org/Libvlc
- http://www.helyar.net/2009/libvlc-media-player-in-c/ (Shows how to DllImport and call the C code from C#)